# How to create a UI interface to trigger playwright test?

Tags: playwright

I have been given the task of creating a UI interface with a button that triggers a Playwright test. The interface should also be able to pass parameters, such as the URL or browser type. I have imported my test function using an API, and it is currently working. However, I am unable to pass the page object because it is not wrapped in the test function.
After I created page object manually, it throws error:

`throw new Error([Playwright Test did not expect ${title} to be called here., Most common reasons include:, - You are calling ${title} in a configuration file., - You are calling ${title} in a file that is impo rted by the configuration file., - You have two different versions of @playwright/test. This usually happens,   when one of the dependencies in your package.json depends on @playwright/test.].join('\n'));`

I thought it might be telling me that don't call test function in my API.

I am trying to write an API and abstract the methods from the Playwright test file. Then, I plan to import these methods in the API to call them. My expectation is that the API will run successfully, and I will be able to pass the test fixtures to it.

I was wondering if there is a better way to approach this, or if I should continue with my current method and make some adjustments.

Thank you.

My github repo: https://github.com/LunaGoodnight/react-trigger-playwright

Answer (score 0):

> I have been given the task of creating a UI interface with a button
> that triggers a Playwright test.

Would it be enough to use the Playwright UI Mode instead of creating something yourself? See this Youtube video: [What's new in Playwright 1.32](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jF0yA-JLQW0).

[image]

And if you write your Playwright test cases in such a way that you have variables at the top, you could perhaps use them to parametrize everything directly in the `Source` view in Playwright UI Mode.

Comment: Thanks. Could I deploy it as a website?